# How to Efficiently Manage and Submit Form Data in React with Redux Integration

Tags: reactjs, forms, frontend

My application is based on React and Redux.

As for my case, I use Redux just for the first data initialization.
Whenever anything changes, I do not update the store.

The server side of my application sends nested data already typed to the client side.

As part of the application, I have a pretty complex form with strings, numbers, boolean (checkboxes and toggles), and multi-selections. All of the inputs are controlled

I'm struggling to understand what is the most common method and the right way to control and send the data back to the server side.

My requirements are:

1. **Form Data Management for Controlled Submissions:** To see form changes and control the submission button, I want to keep the typed data, so that I can compare it to the original data from the server.

   My purpose is to control the data to make the form "smart" and to keep button restrictions if I make a change and then revert back.

   Ensure that the button can only be pressed if there has been an actual data change.
2. **Handling Multiple Values for the Same Field:** My form needs to support fields with multiple values, ideally managed as an array or set. I'm looking for a streamlined way to handle this scenario, as my initial attempts with hidden inputs and collecting them post-submission felt cumbersome and not quite right.
3. **Efficient Data Submission:**  It's crucial for me to ensure that only the data that has changed is sent back to the server, while also maintaining the original data types. For instance, if the server sends an integer, I need to submit any changes as an integer, not as a string or any other type. I'm seeking a method to achieve this without losing the type integrity, which seems to be a challenge with approaches like using FormData objects.

I appreciate insights or references to best practices, libraries, or patterns that could help address these requirements effectively.

[react](/questions/tagged/react) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [redux](/questions/tagged/redux) [form](/questions/tagged/form)

My approach has included experimenting with FormData objects and utilizing regular form inputs and events to manage and submit the data.

Comment: I believe Redux Form could be of use here: https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/? Also, check React Hook Form: https://www.react-hook-form.com/